# Drag marker event not detected in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I've got a problem with the event OnDragClickListener.I have an activity which calls a fragment where I load a map of Google Maps.

***MainActivity.java***

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MainActivityFragment fragment = (MainActivityFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_location);

        fragment.setLng(2.136342);
        fragment.setLat(41.393751);
        fragment.updateCameraLocation(null);
    }

}
```

***MainActivityFragment.java***

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment{
    private final static String TAG = "MainActivityFragment";
    private final static int INITIAL_ZOOM = 17;

    private MapView mapView;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private ArrayList<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();

    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "Latitud: " + Double.toString(this.getLat()) + " Longitud: " + Double.toString(this.getLng()));

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

          // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(true);

        map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                                          Log.d(TAG, "Latitud: " + Double.toString(latLng.latitude) + " Longitud: " + Double.toString(latLng.longitude));
                                          String title = "Marcador nuevo!!!";
                                          String snippet = "Más snippet!!!";

                                          createMarker(new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), title, snippet);

                                          Log.d(TAG, "size después de add: " + markers.size() + " marker idMarker 0: " + markers.get(0).getId());

                                          Log.d(TAG, "Longitud marker: " + markers.size() + " marker idMarker 1: " + markers.get(0).getId());
                                      }
                                  }

        );

        map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {


                                             Log.d(TAG, "id marker: " + marker.getId());
                                             Log.d(TAG, "total markers: " + markers.size());

                                             return false;
                                         }
                                     }
        );

        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerDragStart!!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerDrag!!!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onMarkerDragEnd!!!");
            }
        });

        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //updateCameraLocation(null);
        //createMarker();
        Log.d(TAG, "Fin de onCReateView");
        return v;
    }

    public void updateCameraLocation(Integer zoom){
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = null;

        if (zoom == null){
            cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(this.getLat(), this.getLng()), this.INITIAL_ZOOM);
        }else{
            cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(this.getLat(), this.getLng()), zoom.intValue());
        }

        if (cameraUpdate != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Vamos a crear los markers");
            String txt = getResources().getString(R.string.txt_you_here);
            String snippet = "Snippet!!!";
            createMarker(new LatLng(this.getLat(), this.getLng()), txt, snippet);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }

    private void createMarker(LatLng latLng, String title, String snippet){

        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(title)
                        .snippet(snippet)
                        .draggable(true)
        );
        marker.setVisible(true);
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        String idMarker = marker.getId();
        Log.d(TAG, "id marker: " + idMarker);
        markers.add(marker);
        Log.d(TAG, "size después de put: " + markers.size() + " marker idMarker: " + markers.get(0).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }


    public void setLat(double lat){
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLat(){
        return this.lat;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng){
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public double getLng(){
        return this.lng;
    }
}
```

The methods `onMapClick(LatLng latLng)` and `onMarkerClick(Marker marker)` works fine, but the methods `onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker)`, `onMarkerDrag(Marker marker)` and `onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker)` doesn't work.

What happened?

Comment: for the `onMarkerDrag()` event to fire, first you'll have to long press the marker and then drag..On long press, the marker will become a little shaky and then you will be able to drag the marker.

Comment: Sorry, but before to drag the marker you have to press long this marker and then start drag, drag, and end drag. And this events never fired :(

Answer (score 0):

In order for the marker to be capable of dragging, you need to implement `marker.setDraggable(true);` when you create the marker.

Comment: Sorry KayAnn's but when I create the marker I make it draggable with .draggable(true).  Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() .position(latLng) .title(title) .snippet(snippet) .draggable(true)

Comment: are you testing this in an emulator?

Comment: Because in the case the bool is set, ideally it should work. But in an emulator you wouldn't be able to test touch gestures. In that case for testing purpose you would have to implement `mouseover` event.

Comment: Y es,  I'm testing in an emulator. I'll try to test un a tablet. I'll tell you later if it works por if it doesn't work!!! Thank you @KayAnn!!!